# Show selected image before upload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-upload

In one of my web application I have to implement a image upload. But I need to show the image(s) before upload in my browser . I found the following javascript code and pretty working in all browsers except Safari, IE.

```
function handleFiles(files) {

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {


        $('.img_error_con').html("Invalid image file.");
            $('.img_error_con').fadeIn(200);
            return false;


        continue;
    }


    var img=document.getElementById('fake_img');
    img.src = file;
    img.onload = function() {


    };


    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

}
```

Please help me to solve the issue in Safari . or any HTML5 method for doing this job ?

Please help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to HTML5 non-supported everywhere features...

Safari doesnt support FileReader on windows at least for the moment ,so your script is not going to work just with javascript. I guess IE ( which version ? ) doesnt too.

Comment: thanks for your reply and I am facing the prob with Safari and IE 8 . Any HTML5 method for this purpose ?